# How to trigger mDNS broadcast by software?

Tags: android, networking, network-programming, android-networking, zeroconf

When a device supporting zero-configuration is plugged into an Android device's Ethernet port, it immediately starts to send mDNS packets to broadcast its services to the Android device. I am wondering if there is a software equivalent of Ethernet cable plugging-in that triggers this broadcast.  Disabling then enabling Ethernet does not do the trick.

Comment: Did you get the answer for this question? Please jot it here

Comment: @AMIamitekh No,unfortunately.